# RestKit CoreData: modify value before relationship mapping

Tags: ios, core-data, mapping, restkit, relationship

I have got a problem that is blow my mind for a couple of weeks.

From the server I receive JSON like this:

```
"response": {
    "items": [
        {
            "type": "post",
            "source_id": -22558194, //Negative value
            "date": 1394777763,
            "post_id": 490216,
        },
        {
            "type": "post",
            "source_id": 4487587, //Positive value
            "date": 1394777320,           
        }],
     "profiles": [
        {
            "uid": 4487587,
            "first_name": "Name",
            "last_name": "Name",
        }],
      "groups": [
        {
            "gid": 22558194,
            "name": "USA",
            "screen_name": "all_about_usa",
        }]
```

}

From "items" positive "source_id" means it should be connected to object from "profile" to key "uid", negative "source_id" means it should be connected to object from "groups" to key "gid".

I connected *positive* source_id to profiles with no problem, but for *negative* it's kind of tricky because *source_id* is negative value but *gid* is positive value. I tried to override NSManagedObject setter method but without any success.

```
- (void) setIdentifer:(NSNumber *)identifer
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"identifer"];
    int modifiedIdentifer = [identifer intValue]; 
    //Make negative
    [self setPrimitiveValue:@(-modifiedIdentifer) forKey:@"identifer"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"identifer"];
}
```

In fact I want to modify *gid* just before relationship mapping. How can I achieve that?

Thanx

Comment: Did you look at using KVC validation?

Comment: @Wain , no, I don't need validation because negative value is valid. It's VK api. They use negative value in source_id for groups' sources and positive for users' sources.

Comment: You can use validation for mutation too...

Comment: @Wain, doesn't working. Think RestKit perform relationships mapping before actually putting in DB.

Comment: You're using foreign key mapping? Show how. Why is the `gid` value not just negative...